# Typescript, class is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've searched and the answers I found didn't help me.

I created a class in Typescript and wanted to import it to another Typescript-File
via

```
import '../EventDTO';
```

Than I looked into the converted file (main.js) where all my typescript files are converted to. In there, there's also the class which I've written, but when I want to use it in my file like:

```
eventList[i] = new EventDTO(data[i].id);
```

I get this Error in my browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: EventDTO is not defined

EventDTO class:

```
class EventDTO{

    id: number;

    constructor(_id: number){
            this.id = _id;
    }

    getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
```

So, how can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would need to add **`export`** keyword

```
export class EventDTO{

    id: number;

    constructor(_id: number){
            this.id = _id;
    }

    getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just export the class in EventDTO.ts:

```
export class EventDTO { ... }
```