# Why is my code getting stuck when instantiating a class in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am parsing a string for some data and then creating objects from this data. I am able to parse the data fine but for some reason my code stalls when I try to make a new object? I suspect I am not doing this correctly, here is my code:

This is my reading date class:

```
class ReadingDate {
year: number;
month: number;
day: number;
hour: number;
minute: number;
second: number;

public constructor(y: number, m: number,
                 d: number, h: number,
                 min: number, s: number) {
  this.year = y;
  this.month = m;
  this.day = d;
  this.hour = h;
  this.minute = min;
  this.second = s;
}

public toString() : string{
    return (this.year+"-"+this.month+"-"+this.day+" "+this.hour+":"+this.minute+":"+this.second);
  }
 }
```

And here is a snippet of code where I try to create a new ReadingDate in another class:

```
static parseDate(date: string){
  console.log("parsing date"); // this prints fine
  let array = date.split(" ", 2);
  let dateArray = array[0].split("-", 3);
  let timeArray = array[1].split(":", 3);
  console.log("numbers \n1: " + parseInt(dateArray[0]) +" type: " + typeof(parseInt(dateArray[0]))
    +"\n2: " + parseInt(dateArray[1]) + " type: " + typeof(parseInt(dateArray[1]))
    +"\n3: " + parseInt(dateArray[2]) + " type: " + typeof(parseInt(dateArray[2]))
    +"\n4: " + parseInt(timeArray[0]) + " type: " + typeof(parseInt(timeArray[0]))
    +"\n5: " + parseInt(timeArray[1]) + " type: " + typeof(parseInt(timeArray[1]))
    +"\n6: " + parseInt(timeArray[2]) + " type: " + typeof(parseInt(dateArray[2]))
 );
  console.log("parsed date"); // this prints fine
  var parsedDate = new ReadingDate(
    parseInt(dateArray[0]),
    parseInt(dateArray[1]),
    parseInt(dateArray[2]),
    parseInt(timeArray[0]),
    parseInt(timeArray[1]),
    parseInt(timeArray[2])
  );
  console.log("reached here"); //this never prints
  console.log("newlyParsedDate: "+ parsedDate.toString()); //this never prints
  return parsedDate; //this never happens
}
```

And here is an example of me calling parseDate():

```
static parseReading(reading: string) {
    console.log("inparser: "+reading);
    let array = reading.split(",", 4);
    let date = ParserProvider.parseDate(array[0]);
    console.log("finished parsing date"); //this does not print and nothing past it happens
    let location = array[1];
    let val = array[2]==1?true:false;
    let battery = array[3];
    console.log("inparser: "+location,val,battery); //does not print
```

}

With an example date of "2018-10-16 10:32:02" the console output looks like this:

```
parser.ts:17 inparser: 2018-10-16 10:41:22,living,1,16
parser.ts:31 parsing date
parser.ts:33 2018-10-16
parser.ts:34 10:32:02
parser.ts:37 parsed date
parser.ts:38 numbers 
             1: 2018 type: number
             2: 10 type: number
             3: 16 type: number
             4: 10 type: number
             5: 32 type: number
             6: 2 type: number
```

It doesn't give me any errors but my program appears to just stop doing anything after I try to make a ReadingDate object.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: updated with toString method

EDIT 2: updated with example of parseDate being called, some extra console.logs and the console output when it is called

EDIT 3: Ok so when i put a try/catch around where I am trying to make the object like this:

```
try{var parsedDate = new ReadingDate(
      parseInt(dateArray[0]),
      parseInt(dateArray[1]),
      parseInt(dateArray[2]),
      parseInt(timeArray[0]),
      parseInt(timeArray[1]),
      parseInt(timeArray[2])
      );}
catch(error){console.log(error);}
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: ReadingDate is not defined
at Function.webpackJsonp.197.ParserProvider.parseDate (VM14753 main.js:300)
at Function.webpackJsonp.197.ParserProvider.parseReading (VM14753 main.js:276)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.195.HomePage.handleReading (VM14753 main.js:146)
at VM14753 main.js:141
at VM14752 vendor.js:75337
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Events.publish (VM14752 vendor.js:75336)
at ClientImpl.MqttProvider.onMessageArrived (VM14753 main.js:228)
at ClientImpl.LibraryFactory.ClientImpl._receiveMessage (VM14750 paho-mqtt.js:1502)
at ClientImpl.LibraryFactory.ClientImpl._receivePublish (VM14750 paho-mqtt.js:1477)
```

EDIT 4: Fixed! See my answer below and refer to this StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977370/typescript-class-is-not-defined)

Comment: So is the `parseDate()` a method of the ReadingDate class? Public is inferred for the constructor and should be removed. I do believe you'll run into some other issues related to the values, but start with this. You do realize there is a method that provide all of these values without you parsing them?

Comment: PS you could just: `constructor(public year: number, ...)` then you don't have to declare, pass & assign

Comment: Where you are attempting to instantiate ReadingDate, have you performed a `console.log(parseInt(dataArray[0]))` etc first to ensure each array element is going to pass over the expected values? Are all of those set as expected?

Comment: Does ReadingDate implement toString()?

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse yes reading date implements toString()

Comment: @Maegz could you then update your question with the implementation?

Comment: @RandyCasburn parseData is a method in another class not in ReadingDate

Comment: @bilpor Yep i have checked the values and their types and they are all as expected

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse done :) I also added another console.log statement in the parseDate method before the toString() one, just to double check whether that would print out if there was no mention of the toString() method and it still doesn't print

Comment: Please provide an example of how this code is called, with an example of the value of `date` being passed into `parseDate`. In other words, a [mcve].

Comment: Could you post a sample date that you are parsing?

Comment: try{var parsedDate = new ReadingDate(
    parseInt(dateArray[0]),
    parseInt(dateArray[1]),
    parseInt(dateArray[2]),
    parseInt(timeArray[0]),
    parseInt(timeArray[1]),
    parseInt(timeArray[2])
  );}catch(error){console.log(error);}

Comment: can you log at the beginning and end of the constructor?

Comment: @huseinRoncevic Sample date: "2018-10-16 10:32:02" (quotes are just to indicate it is a string)

Comment: @HereticMonkey check updated post, does that suffice?

Comment: @Osama I don't know why I didn't think to try this! I will edit the results into my post

Comment: what would be the result if you try catch the object creating

Comment: @Osama See the bottom of my post

Comment: Pretty obvious: _ReferenceError: ReadingDate is not defined_ what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks guys I fixed it please see my answer below! Thank you for all your help you have all been amazing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript, class is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977370/typescript-class-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help specially @osama for suggesting the try/catch to find the error. Turns out all I needed to do was export my ReadingDate class and then import it into my Parser File. Seems to be the same/similar issue as this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977370/typescript-class-is-not-defined) .

Comment: My dear @Maegz remember to use export and import always

Comment: And please always post the whole class.